# how to send multiple ajax request and process the multiple request

Tags: php, ajax

Below is the ajax code to perform the subjected action but it is implemented in a manner of elaboration instead of do it with simple one.

Here implemented separate code for each ajax request and response.

please see the below code:

```
 <html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-       1.7.1.min.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">

       $(document).ready(function(){

             $("#country").change(function(){
                 var country=$("#country").val();


                 $.ajax({
                    type:"post",
                    url:"getstate.php",
                    data:'typeId='+country,
                    success:function(data){
                          $("#state").html(data);
                     }
                 });


           });
       });
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

       $(document).ready(function(){

             $("#state").change(function(){

                 var state=$("#state").val();

                 $.ajax({
                    type:"post",
                    url:"getdistrict.php",
                    data:'typeId='+state,
                    success:function(data){
                          $("#district").html(data);
                    }
                 });


           });
       });
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

       $(document).ready(function(){

             $("#district").change(function(){

                 var district=$("#district").val();

                 $.ajax({
                    type:"post",
                    url:"getward.php",
                    data:'typeId='+district,
                    success:function(data){
                          $("#ward").html(data);
                    }
                 });


           });
       });
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

       $(document).ready(function(){

             $("#ward").change(function(){

                 var ward=$("#ward").val();

                 $.ajax({
                    type:"post",
                    url:"getslum.php",
                    data:'typeId='+ward,
                    success:function(data){

                          $("#slum").html(data);
                    }
                 });


           });
       });
  </script>


 </head>
 <body>
    Country : &nbsp;

    <select name="country" id="country">
      <option>-select your country-</option>
    <?php 
    error_reporting(E_ALL); 
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    include "dbconfig.php"; 

    $result=sqlsrv_query($conn,"SELECT [CountryId],[Country] from   toilet_Country order by Country");
    while($country=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)){

    echo "<option value = $country[CountryId]>$country[Country]</option>";

    } ?>
    </select> <br><br>


    State :
    &emsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <select name="state" id="state">
        <option>-select your state-</option>
    </select> <br><br>

     District : &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <select name="district" id="district">
        <option>-select your District-</option>
    </select> <br><br>

    Ward : &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <select name="ward" id="ward">
        <option>-select your ward-</option>
    </select> <br><br>

    Slum : &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <select name="slum" id="slum">
        <option>-select your slum name-</option>
    </select> <br><br>





  </body>
  </html>
```

And i have written code in separate files to retrieve country,state,district information from database.

I am unaware of these ajax call request and response an looking for advise how can i make this code portable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could calculate how long one request takes and work with a timeout to deplay the follup-requests.

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do?

Comment: [async false](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) maybe you're looking for synchronous treatement?

Comment: @MostafaTalebi I am using five multiple dependent drop down list to fetch values from database for each drop down so, i want to send multiple values through ajax request and do response for multiple dependent drop down list.

Comment: @haider with dependent, you mean for instance you select a country from a drop down, and in the next drop the list of cities would be populated?

Comment: @MostafaTalebi yes you are right!, and please check the code and what we want to do make changes in our code?